# How to check that the constructor in a class correctly sets the property in a new object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

The question is as follows
"This test checks that the constructor in the Command class correctly sets the commandType property in the new object."

im not sure how to set it up

Here is the code that I have that is failing. The first test works but the second we are told we do not have to use assert.throws so i tried using a strictequals but am not sure how to go about setting it up.

```
const assert = require('assert');
const Command = require('../command.js');

describe("Command class", function() {

  it("throws error if command type is NOT passed into constructor as the first parameter", function() {
    assert.throws(
      function() {
        new Command();
      },
      {
        message: 'Command type required.'
      }
    );
  });

  it("constructor should set command type",function(){
    let contructorCheck = Command(commandtype, 7);
    assert.sctrictEqual(contructorCheck, "commandtype")
  });

});
```

and this is the class that i am unit testing

```
class Command {
  constructor(commandType, value) {
    this.commandType = commandType;
    if (!commandType) {
      throw Error("Command type required.");
    }
    this.value = value;
  }

}
```

Comment: I usually use `jest` ,  but I'd say you're almost there... `assert.sctrictEqual(contructorCheck.commandType, commandtype)`

Comment: Also you forgot the `new` keyword in the second test

Comment: this is telling me that commandtype isnt defined

Answer (score 0):

```
it("constructor should set command type", function(){
    let constructorCheck = new Command('abc', 123);
    assert.strictEqual(constructorCheck.commandType, 'abc');
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.